# tkinter custom widget collecting

Tags: python, tkinter, collections, widget

I'm searching for a tkinter custom widget collection that I can include in a application designer I'm writing in 100% Python but haven't had much luck yet.  I figured out a way to do a table for instance, but would like to save myself the work if there's a good implementation out there.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of packages for pure Python custom widget creation with a little more searching online.  One is Python megawidgets, at pmw.sourceforge.net, which, according to their documentation:

*"is a toolkit for building high-level compound widgets in Python using the Tkinter module. It consists of a set of base classes and a library of flexible and extensible megawidgets built on this foundation.  These megawidgets include notebooks, comboboxes, selection widgets, panes widgets, scrollable widgets, and dialog windows."*

A different approach is writing custom widgets yourself using the Widget Construction Kit, at effbot.org/zone/wck.htm.  This provides a base Widget class with primitive drawing methods, such as for borders, text, and colors, along with a basic but complete set of event definitions for binding your event handlers to your custom widgets.  It has some good advice on doing animated widgets, such as drag and drop.

If anybody knows of any other packages of widgets or construction toolkit APIs, feel free to post it here.  Developers will appreciate having a larger selection in a single location.